# How to define module output in the description

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to include module output in the description. Is it possible to add module output in the description?

**example:**

```
  description = <<EOF
   application creation failed. Pls check the page and deploy
   Make sure that you are passing the module.application.values
EOF
```

**Error:**

```
Error: Invalid template interpolation value   
   
 
  23: EOF   
    |----------------   
    | module.application.values is object with 7 attributes   
   
Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

Comment: The code is about ` module.application.values`, yet you haven't showed where and how do you use ` module.application.values`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking about. Can you please extend your answer and show us what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but i don't think is possible, you can try expanding the module output in string, i never tried it but i am pretty sure that is not admissible.

```
description = <<EOF
   application creation failed. Pls check the page and deploy
   Make sure that you are passing the ${module.application.values}
EOF
```

Comment: It's possible but it only depends on what the goal is.

Comment: Sorry, it can be done in the `value` of the output, not sure about description. :)